# Can I get function input in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

if I want to know input, how can I do?
for example,

```
def hello(*something):
    return something
hello("a == 1")
```

then the result will be 'a == 1'.
but if I type like this

```
hello(a == 1)
```

then the result will be 'True'.
I want to make

```
hello(a == 1) -> a == 1
hello(b == 1) -> b == 1
hello(a == 2) -> a == 2
```

how can I print something without being string?
(I hope just change function)
(Also, not just this case, I want to utilize that, so please don't say that why do I have to do like that)

Comment: No, this cannot be done in Python. In fact, I can't think of *any* programming language where something equivalent can be done. "Also, not just this case, I want to utilize that, so please don't say that why do I have to do like that" It is only possible to help you with a proper understanding of what *problem you hope to solve* by doing this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think it could technically be done by reading the file and then converting that specific part to a string and then return that but that doesn't seem like a good implementation anyways. Either how this sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: (I wouldn't call that a solution because in the general case, the source code is not guaranteed to be available to the running program.)

Comment: I'm trying to make platform so thanks for the tip I think I have to change the method

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Well, there *were* [fexpr:s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fexpr) in ancient LISP dialects, but I think those have decayed from "programming languages" to "programming legends" by now. =)

Answer (score 0):

you can't as typing `a == 1` is evaluated to True by python first then it is passed to function. even if you type input(a==2) it will gonna throw following error

```py
>>> input(a==2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

But why you need to have it not in string format? `a == 1` is an operation and to print the way it was written only thing you can do it's put it in quote like this:

```
 hello("a == 1")
```

What's the problem to print it in string format?

Comment: I'm trying to make platform so I wanted to make percieve what they input without being string...but thanks for answer!

Comment: @김도훈 input can be converted to string, in fact if you use `input` then the returned value is a string already

Comment: I mean input where using function. But thanks!

Comment: You can use string format and then convert last part to interger:
interger = something.split(' == ')[1]
Use that inside of the function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a certain number in your function, just input this number and than cast it to int:

```
def hello(something):
    a = int(something)

    return a

hello(1)
```

And if you want to print an integer then just

```
print(f'a = {hello(1)}')

# a = 1
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to be what OP wanted